# How to run the Tabbar without clicking the Tabs in Android

Tags: android

I have a Tab bar application with two tabs named "Tab1" and "Tab2".

Whenever I launch the application ,the Tab Bar runs and the "Tab1" in the Tab Bar get selected and it runs an Activity, because I have used setCurrentTab(0) method.

So how can I run the Second Tab named "Tab2" simultaneously along with the "Tab1" without clicking. Here I cannot use setCurrentTab(1),because I have already used setCurrentTab(0).

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by running the Second Tab simultaneously? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Soham whenever the app launches i need to load both the two tabs but the first tab should get highlighted.Because both the tabs contains the WebViews i.e.,two instances should be created one for Tab1 and one for Tab2.But in the above whenever i click on the Tab the instance for that view will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first navigate to the second tab then come to the first tab.

setCurrentTab(1);
setCurrentTab(0);

so the second tab will be onPause state do whatever you want to do on second tab.